# File upload via Ajax in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to upload a file through ajax in Laravel.

```
$("#stepbutton2").click(function(){
            var uploadFile = document.getElementById("largeImage");
            if( ""==uploadFile.value){


            }
            else{
                var fd = new FormData();

                fd.append( "fileInput", $("#largeImage")[0].files[0]);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/nominations/upload/image',
                    data: fd,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data.uploaded==true){
                            alert(data.url);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(err){
                        alert(err);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

I'm passing the file input to the php script.

```
public function image(){

$file = Input::file('fileInput');
    $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileName = md5(time()).".$ext";

    $destinationPath = "uploads/".date('Y').'/'.date('m').'/';
    $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    $path = $file->getRealPath();
    return Response::json(["success"=>true,"uploaded"=>true, "url"=>$path]);


    }
```

I'm getting a the response as

```
{"success":true,"uploaded":true,"url":false}
```

The request Payload is

```
------WebKitFormBoundary30GMDJXOsygjL0ZS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileInput"; filename="DSC06065 copy.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: Try getting the path before moving the file

Comment: The response is `{"success":true,"uploaded":true,"url":"C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php7A29.tmp"}`

Comment: And... that's not what you want?

Comment: I want to upload the file to a folder and return the URL to the ajax.

Comment: `{"success":true,"uploaded":true,"url":"\/uploads\/2015\/02\/"}`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski : Thanks it worked. Kindly make it as an answer

Comment: i have exactly the same problem. can i have the answer, please?

Comment: @Peter: check the comments above. It worked for me.

Comment: in the comments above i cannot see any posts by @JonathanLonowski. i am on mobile now, does it matter?

Comment: @Peter: added it below.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

```
 public function image(){

         $file = Input::file('fileInput');
             $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
             $fileName = md5(time()).".$ext";

             $destinationPath = "uploads/".date('Y').'/'.date('m').'/';
             $moved_file = $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
             $path = $moved_file->getRealPath();
             return Response::json(["success"=>true,"uploaded"=>true, "url"=>$path]);


             }
```

Get the path after assigning it to a new variable.